# Как добавить LinearLayout (horizontal) программно в LinearLayout (vertical)?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

Добавляются программно элементы в LinearLayout (vertical), мне необходимо в этот LinearLayout (vertical) добавить два элемента в строку, то есть horizontal.

LinearLayout (vertical) прописан в макете.

Как это сделать? Как я понимаю, нужно добавить LinearLayout (horizontal) программно в LinearLayout (vertical). Правильно ли это? Но как я не пробовала реализовать это, выходят одни траблы

Как я вижу, так как LinearLayout (horizontal) является дочерним LinearLayout (vertical), то должно происходить сначала действие упрощенно говоря "Разместить элемент вертикально" (то есть с новой строки), а далее уже "Разместить этот объект horizontal"

Наглядный образец(как должно выглядеть):

1) Элемент

2) Элемент

3) ЭлементЭлемент

4) Элемент

Элементы добавляются программно, их количество неизвестно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это

```
public void addHorizontalElement(View left, View right) {
    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    container.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    container.addView(left);
    container.addView(right);
    linearLayoutVert.add(container);
}
```

замените getContext() на контекст вашего приложения